# Where to find a list of pandas **kwargs?

Tags: pandas

There is no link (or description) to **kwargs in pandas documentation.

For example I need to use [pandas write_frame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.sql.write_frame.html).
How to find a list of **kwargs?

Comment: @bernie that just dumps the text, the point being that write_frame wraps another function and there is no doc for what `kwargs` supports, as an aside `write_frame` is deprecated (depending on your version) and you should use [`to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/io.html#io-sql)

Comment: @bernie nothing about **kwargs

Comment: my mistake, guys. i deleted my erroneous comment. thanks for the added info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically anything that's important will be a documented option.  In this case, the only option available in kwargs is 'append,' which is a deprecated alias to 'if_exists.'